# upgrading to Dual AC set up. Land Rover Defender 110 year 2005

Tags: ac, compressor, land-rover

I will have to upgrade the AC Compressor for this Dual Set up. The second AC will be fitted on top of the backside door. Can someone recommend specifications for this AC compressor?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you sure you need a different compressor? Seems to me you could utilize the same compressor, with the addition of the rear AC components, new AC lines, and a lot more refrigerant. I'm not an AC expert, though, so don't know for sure.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.